# Vibrate Not working with Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-vibration

I am trying to set vibrate and sound for notification. For some reason its not working for me :( Here is the code what I am trying

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager();
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        builder.setSound(alarmSound);
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000 });
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msgToDisply))
                .setContentText(msgToDisply).build();
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        stopSelf();
```

And

```
public NotificationManager getNotificationManager() {
        return (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

And I have permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Any clue what's going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you did not declare the Vibrator class to vibrate on Notification.In your notification builder put this code and set the duration of vibrate based on your choose.

```
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
 v.vibrate(500);
```

Comment: But I am using NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: it doesn't matter you must declare vibrate function!by my code or by @Panayiotis code anyway must declare!

Comment: WHy does NotificationBuilder and Notification support setting vibration values though?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing as @StealthRabbi, the above suggestion will work, but its just triggering a vibrate manually, I would have thought the NotificationBuilders.setVibrate() method should handle this!

Comment: This is a hack, not answer to question

Answer (score 5):

add this

```
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Comment: @Achayan can you put he code of your broadcastreceiver?

Comment: Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this
          .getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(2000);

This is working at last .. thanks guys for the help

Comment: Your Welcome:)i told you you can do it with my code:)Im glad i could help:)